# The function to change the content of DIV with jQuery and Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code that should be evoked when a button is clicked:

```
 <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="clear_form (); return false;" class="pure-button">
```

The actual functions removes the text from the textarea and the two buttons from the form:

```
 function clear_form () {
        $("#statement").val('');
        document.submitform.submit.value = "save";
        document.submitform.delete.remove();
        document.submitform.cancel.remove();
 }
```

However, when the button is clicked (in Chrome), the following message appears and the clear_form function does not work.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: clear_form is not defined
```

Does anybody know why that is? Did I misss something?

Comment: Is there any further output in JS console if Chrome?

Comment: I just dont understand why people use inline events when they are using jquery also

Comment: @BatuZet: They're very simple to bind, and there's no delay between the element being available and the handler being assigned. There's much hysteria surrounding inline handlers, but ultimately they're just a valid, alternate way to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8FUq/1/)

**Javascript**

```
function clear_form(){

    $("#statement").val('');
    document.submitform.submit.value = "save";
    document.submitform.delete.remove();
    document.submitform.cancel.remove();

    }

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(){

    alert()

    clear_form();

},false);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" class="pure-button" id='submit'>
```

As stated by **@cookiemonster**, space(s) after function names make(s) no difference.

See the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5H4zh/)

Comment: I didn't vote, but *"There should be no space after function name"* is nonsense. You're just repeating someone else's opinion.

Comment: Prove what? That a space won't make a difference? Just create a demo with a space, and see if it runs. http://jsfiddle.net/5H4zh/

Comment: @cookiemonster monster, see this link http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations , **Function declarations** line.

Comment: I already did. That's what I was responding to. And as I said, you're just repeating someone's opinion. I don't think you understand what that page is. It's a set of coding conventions. It has no bearing on the functionality of the script. And as my demo shows, a space makes no difference.

Comment: @cookiemonster, I've never tried using spaces after function names, so thought that might be the cause, updated my answer.

Comment: "no spaces after a function name" is just a coding convention. The reason this works is that `addEventListener` is within the scope where `clear_form` is visible

Answer (score 2):

When do you declare `function clear_form()` ... is it declared inside of another function? In that case `clear_form()` is locally available in scope of that containing function, only. Attaching click handlers in HTML attributes requires mentioned functions to be declared globally.

If you can't make `clear_form()` global, you still might use `addEventListener()` to add your local function from Javascript instead of using attribute `onclick` in HTML. BTW, this is the preferred way of doing this in websites for separating content and logics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you using that code in your full application.
but I made this full working sample page

try it and let us know if it works with you..

Please this in the head tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clear_form() {
            //    $("#statement").val('');  or load the JQuery Library and us this line
            document.submitform.statement.value = "";  // Used this instead of JQuery
            document.submitform.submit.value = "save";
            document.submitform.delete.remove();
            document.submitform.cancel.remove();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="submitform" id="submitform">
        <textarea id="statement" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea> <br />
        <input type="button" name="delete" value="delete" /><br />
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="clear_form (); return false;" class="pure-button">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```